# Cast from BaseClass to DerivedClass (stored in a list)

Tags: c#, generics

My problem is in how to access the derived class functions and methods from my list storing base items. I am able to do it by creating a new instance of `Item` and using the `as` keyword. However, it feels wrong to have to create a nice instance everytime I want to cast it.

First of is the Generic Class that is going to be stored in the `List`. From this class there will be a multitude of inheritances, for now, I am simply using oner.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    protected Item() {}

    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

A variation of Item (also to be stored in List)

```
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int MinDmg { get; protected set; }

    public Weapon(string name, int mindmg)
    {
        Name = name;
        MinDmg = mindmg;
    }
}
```

Main program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item("Mushroom"));
        Items.Add(new Weapon("Dagger", 2, 4));

        foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + "\n");
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(Weapon))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Damage: " + (Weapon)item.MinDmg + " - " + (Weapon)item.MaxDmg + "\n"); // Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error: The error appears to be that my cast is failing me. As the error states "`Item` does not contain a definition for `MinDmg` and no..."

If I do it along these lines:

```
Weapon w = (Weapon)item;
Console.WriteLine ("Damage: " + w.MinDmg...);
```

It works.

Comment: You can cast it this way: `Weapon w = item as Weapon;`

Comment: Also, you don't need the newlines in `WriteLine` - unless you want an extra line.

Comment: `Weapon w = item as Weapon` isn't that pretty much what I tried with `Weapon w = (Weapon)item;`?

Comment: @Emz `xxx as Type` is equivalent to `(Type)xxx` except that the latter will throw an exception if it cannot make the cast and the first will return null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should say like below cause `qualification x.y` has higher precedence then `casting (T)x`.

so when you say `(Weapon)item.MinDmg` it's first trying to find a property named `mindmg` in Item which doesn't exist. You should rather try it like `((Weapon)item).MinDmg`

```
Console.WriteLine("Damage: " + ((Weapon)item).MinDmg
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way round doing the cast. Look at it this way. If you had another class that inherited from Item that didn't have the `MinDmg` property, it would fail in a completely different way.

What you probably want to do is filter the list like this:

```
var weapons = Items.OfType<Weapon>();
```

This gives you a list of `Weapon` objects.

As a further point to note. I would probably extract the `MinDmg` property into it's own interface too. That way you could have something like this:

```
public interface IDamage
{
    public int MinDmg { get; get; }
}

public class Weapon : Item, IDamage
{
    //Stuff in here to calculate damage perhaps
}

public class Spell : IDamage
{
    //Spells can also cause damage
}
```

Now you can get all of the items that cause damage with this line:

```
var damagingItems = Items.OfType<IDamage>();
```

Comment: So every time that I want to access a specific method I will have to use the Weapons List I take it?

Comment: @Emz Exactly. I've added an extra point about that may be useful but isn't part of your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional notes. I will probably go check in interfaces once I start to understand how things will interact.

Comment: @Emz No problem. Hope this answer helps, if so, don't forget to accept as the answer :)

Comment: Technically, it helped, but it didn't answer the question. I feel an upvote is needed though.

Comment: Well technically you didn't ask a question! :)

Answer (score 0):

To be on a safe side you can do this:

As and is are good keywords to use for this purpose.

```
 if (item is Weapon)
            {
                  Weapon w = item as Weapon; 
                  if ( w != null ) { 
                Console.WriteLine("Damage: " + w.MinDmg + " - " + w.MaxDmg + "\n"); // Error
            }
}
```

You will not have to do conversion again and again.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. However this piece of code was more for testing purposes, I will have a "GetTooltip" function that constructs it later, not needing the casts at all in this case.

Comment: Main point to gather from our replies probably is to when to use (cast) and when to use "as". As I have been in the stage where I did not knew the reason. Since I got to know I always use as - Good luck!